# Leverage Browser Caching Doesn't Cache Javascript and CSS Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis-7, web-config

I have a site running on IIS7, C# .Net 4 and I have set the browser caching to 14 days using the web.config file:

```
<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" />
```

For some reason my .js and .css files return this in the header:

```
Cache-Control   public,max-age=1209600, max-age=86400
```

It's passing both 14 days and 1 day at the same time and the 1 day setting is the overriding value.

Does anyone have any ideas why or how this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked http://serverfault.com/questions/346975/stop-iis-7-5-from-sending-out-cache-control-max-age-on-error-codes ?

Answer (score 1):

try updating your web config by following code under the system.webServer tag.

```
<caching>
                <profiles>

                    <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />
                    <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" />

                </profiles>
            </caching>
            <staticContent>
                <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" 
            cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"
            cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" />
            </staticContent>
```